# replace two characters in one cell

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I am using this query to replace one character in a cell

```
select replace(id,',','')id from table
```

But I want to replace two characters in a cell.
If the cell is having this data `(1,3.1)`, and I want it to look like this `(131)`.
How can I replace two different characters in one cell?

Answer (score 5):

Use TRANSLATE instead of REPLACE().  It replaces each occurrence of a character in the first pattern with its matched character in the second.  To remove characters, simply leave cut short the replacement string:

```
select translate(id, '1,.', '1') id from table
```

Note that the second string cannot be null.  Hence the need to include 1 (or some other character) in both strings.

[Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions216.htm#sthref1701)

Obviously the more characters you need to convert/remove the more attractive TRANSLATE() becomes.  The main use for REPLACE is changing patterns (such as words) rather than individual characters.

Answer (score 4):

Can use

```
select replace(translate(id,',.',' '),' ','') from table;
```

or

```
select regexp_replace('1,3.1','[,.]','') from dual;
```

or

```
select replace(replace(id,',',''),'.','') from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the replace again.

```
select replace(replace(id,',',''), '.','') id from table
```

Comment: translate is much-much better!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(id,',',''),'.','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a regular expression:

```
select regexp_replace(id, '[.,]', '') id from table
```

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm#sthref1424)

Comment: In my experience the regexp functions perform slower - as much as an order of magnitude slower on 10g - compared to their non-regexp equivalents.  So I think it is sensible to use `regexp_replace()`, etc only we really need the power of regular expressions.